# adding select field stops iteration; knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am on the knockoutjs tutorial at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections, and I have lost my iterable item `foreach: seats`. First, my view looked like:

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

and got

[image]

Now I have

view

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: price, optionsText: 'price'"></select></td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

the VM hasn't changed

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    //operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

With this new view, I get

[image]

I know knockout is new, but I can't see why changing a display to a select field should interrupt an iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the console will really help you get the reason why something have gone wrong. In my console I got this with your code.
[image: Error]

So it's said there that price is not defined. Thus we need to check in your model if there is really a price object, and then there was none.
So you should just add `price` property in your model.

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
    self.price = ko.observable();
}
```

Comment: that's right, my coworker always says console. I'm tryin to get used to JS

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the developer console, and you'll see that an error is being thrown:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return seats }" Message: Unable to process binding "value: function
>   (){return price }" Message: price is not defined

So the problem is that you are trying to access `price` which doesn't exist on `SeatReservation`. The rendering for the foreach gets interrupted because of the error that is thrown.

I don't think you want a dropdown for `price`, you just want to display the price for whatever meal they have selected.